# Updating a MongoDB document with PyMongo

Tags: python, mongodb, python-3.x, pymongo, database

I am trying to update a document in a collection:

```
   for bookerName,bookingId in zip(bookerNames,bookingIds):
        Person.update_one({'Name': bookerName}, {'$push': {'Bookings': bookingId}})
```

I am trying to add a new bookingId to the list of Bookings this Person already has.

I receive the following error:

```
bson.errors.InvalidDocument: Cannot encode object: 0
```

From what I understand about this error, it means Mongo don't know how to encode a list, it treats it as a custom type.

However, this is strange since I can do:

```
for bookerName in BookerNames:
    personRecord = {"Name":bookerName,"Bookings":[1,2,3,4]}
    Person.insert_one(personRecord)
```

And it works perfectly.

I have also tried to update using $set and even by deleting the old record and trying to insert a new one with the updated list.

Any idea why this is happening or how can I update a list in a document?

I am using Python 3.5, PyMongo 3.0.3 and MongoDB 3.0.7. Could the difference in version between PyMongo and MondoDB be the issue?

EDIT:

```
for bookerName in bookerNames:
    bookingList = bookersToBookings[bookerName]
    personRecord = {"Name":bookerName,"Bookings":bookingList}
    Person.insert_one(personRecord)
```

Where bookersToBookings is a dictionary mapping bookers to their bookingIds, as list.

This does not work, although if I make a record with a list like [1,2,3], it works.

EDIT 2:

```
for bookerName in bookerNames:
    personRecord = {"Name":bookerName,"Bookings":[]}
    Person.insert_one(personRecord)
for x in Person.find():
    print(x)
```

This works. It prints:

```
{'Name': 'Alice', '_id': ObjectId('56241ad79e44c71641efa383'), 'Bookings': []}
{'Name': 'John', '_id': ObjectId('56241ad79e44c71641efa384'), 'Bookings': []}
{'Name': 'Jane', '_id': ObjectId('56241ad79e44c71641efa385'), 'Bookings': []}
{'Name': 'Mary', '_id': ObjectId('56241ad79e44c71641efa386'), 'Bookings': []}
{'Name': 'Dan', '_id': ObjectId('56241ad79e44c71641efa387'), 'Bookings': []}
```

This also works:

```
for bookerName in bookerNames:
    personRecord = {"Name":bookerName,"Bookings":[1,2,3]}
    Person.insert_one(personRecord)
```

Result:

```
{'Bookings': [1, 2, 3], '_id': ObjectId('56241b029e44c716497b60b2'), 'Name': 'Alice'}
{'Bookings': [1, 2, 3], '_id': ObjectId('56241b029e44c716497b60b3'), 'Name': 'John'}
{'Bookings': [1, 2, 3], '_id': ObjectId('56241b029e44c716497b60b4'), 'Name': 'Jane'}
{'Bookings': [1, 2, 3], '_id': ObjectId('56241b029e44c716497b60b5'), 'Name': 'Mary'}
{'Bookings': [1, 2, 3], '_id': ObjectId('56241b029e44c716497b60b6'), 'Name': 'Dan'}
```

Even this works:

```
for bookerName in bookerNames:
    y = [1,2,3,4]
    personRecord = {"Name":bookerName,"Bookings":[x for x in y]}
    Person.insert_one(personRecord)
```

Result:

```
{'_id': ObjectId('56241b5a9e44c7165395a0f0'), 'Bookings': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'Name': 'Alice'}
{'_id': ObjectId('56241b5a9e44c7165395a0f1'), 'Bookings': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'Name': 'John'}
{'_id': ObjectId('56241b5a9e44c7165395a0f2'), 'Bookings': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'Name': 'Jane'}
{'_id': ObjectId('56241b5a9e44c7165395a0f3'), 'Bookings': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'Name': 'Mary'}
{'_id': ObjectId('56241b5a9e44c7165395a0f4'), 'Bookings': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'Name': 'Dan'}
```

This, however, does not work:

```
for bookerName in bookerNames:
    y = bookersToBookings[bookerName]
    personRecord = {"Name":bookerName,"Bookings":[x for x in y]}
    Person.insert_one(personRecord)
```

bookersToBookings looks like this:

```
{'Mary': [5, 9], 'Jane': [4, 7, 8, 13, 14], 'Alice': [0, 6, 10], 'Dan': [12], 'John': [1, 2, 3, 11]}
```

EDIT 3 - SOLVED:

For $%#^ sake! The list was made of numpy64 ints, not python ints. It works now.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you show what's your bookerName and bookingId look like? I reckon either one is invalid like wrapping in another {...} object as the error suggested

Comment: @Anzel They are lists. I checked with type(bookerName) == type([]) ( Maybe not the most elegant way but I should work ). They are read from a cvs file. Their values are: bookerNames = ["John","Jane","Mary","Alice","Dan"] and  bookingIds = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14].

Comment: you cannot update_one with a list as the first {...} in your query. The first {...} in your query tries to look up the matching result before updating with your second {...}. That's why you have the error.

Comment: @Anzel, I am not sure I understand. I query for a record with the "Name" bookerName. Also, I have changed my code and I am now trying to directly insert the bookingList ( see edit ). I get the same error.

Comment: ok I mis-read your above comment, thought you're filtering a list. let me put together another answer to justify it

Comment: In your first example, is bookingId a list?

Comment: @Anzel, no, bookingId is an element of bookingIds.

Comment: Are you sure this:  `bookersToBookings[bookerName]` results in a list? do a print to verify.

Comment: That is laughable, and no wonder I don't get what your problem is. Glad you've it solved. I have removed my answer so feel free to just remove your question, or provide an answer so other people can read this as a reference

Comment: Yes, it was a list, but it was a list of numpy ints not python ints, that's why Mongo was treating it like a custom type.